# Прогноз погоды на Python

Tags: python

Нужно сделать именно прогноз погоды, НЕ ТЕКУЩУЮ погоду в определенном месте, как это делает pyowm, а именно прогноз, например, хочу узнать погоду в Минске в 15:00 через 7 дней.
На всякий случай прикрепляю код pyowm, где определяется именно текущая погода в определенном месте:

```
from pyowm import OWM

owm = OWM('my API')

while True:
    try:
        place = input('What city do you want to know the weather in? Enter correct city name: ')
        monitoring = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
        weather = monitoring.weather
        status = weather.detailed_status
        print(f'It is {status} in {place} now.')
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: ну берете и просто вместо метода `weather_at_place()` используете `forecast_at_place`, как это указанно в документации к `pyowm`...

Comment: https://openweathermap.org/city/625144

Answer (score 0):

Берите инфу отсюда: https://thecode.media/weather-3/

Тут написано как сделать такого телеграм бота. Возьмите отсюда все нужное вам.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/915122)